# Change Button Text Using jQuery When Value = Something Specific

Tags: jquery

I need to change the value of a button on a page using jQuery when the value = "Add" as shown below on page load.

I can't use name or even the style in the DIV because the button has a bunch of uniquely generated code that changes every page load and I need to reliably change the value from "Add" to "Select This Choice". I've tried a variety of examples I've found on this site, but I haven't found one that works.

Also, there are other buttons on this page, so it's only the buttons with a value of "Add" that I want to change.

Here's an example of the button (Name, ID, and on-click events are summarized)

```
<div id="DivPanelListerWrapper">
<input type="button" name="UniqueNameEveryTimeButtonIsGenerated" value="Add" onclick="javascript event" id="UniqueIDEveryTimeButtonIsGenerated" title="Add" class=" TextButton">
</div>
```

Has anyone done something like this before, and if so, do you have any suggestions for tackling this? I have to imagine it's doable, but I'm at a loss. Thx in advance!

I tried a variety of solutions and put them within jQuery's contains function - something like this (this is a hot mess, but an attempt).

```
<script>
$("button > Div:contains('Add')").text().replace("Add, "Select This Choice");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=button][value=Add]').attr('value', 'Select This Choice');
```

Comment: LOL - that's it for sure. Thanks for the assist - appreciate it!

Comment: Actually, one more question - is there a way to do the same thing with "contains" but on the ID attribute? So for example if the ID of a span contains XXXX then .attr('value', 'Select This Choice');

Comment: @njCoder, yep, something like [id*=XXX] should go. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/